# DATEDIFF for two columns but only returning for less than 1 year

Tags: sql, sql-server

I’m looking for the syntax to return only records that are less than 1 year in length between the columns of when they were purchased and when then were actually processed (relates to SLA)

So something like…

```
Select Products
From Table
Where process_date < DATEDIFF(year, 1, purchase_date)
```

... granted this is in a much bigger query, but when i add this datediff syntax this is what happens, but when i remove it the query runs... a little help?

*Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Operand type clash: date is incompatible with int*

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for `DATEADD()`:

```
Where process_date < DATEADD(year, 1, purchase_date)
```

`DATEDIFF()` does not do what you want.  It counts the number of year boundaries between two dates.  So the following are both "1 year" apart:

```
2019-12-31 and 2020-01-01
2019-01-01 and 2020-12-31
```